# Convert text Amount to decimal - ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

In my source file I have amount column with values

eg:

```
Amount
380.00
2,435.00
```

So when I try to load this in to the destination, I wish to convert the value in to `int(12)`.

How to do this conversion by removing `.` and `,` from the text and load in to the destination.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the fractional part? Truncate/Floor? Ceiling? Round?

Comment: Also, should the title of the question be edited to converting to `int` or should the body of your question be edited to change `int` to `decimal`.  My answer is written from the perspective of converting to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSIS, you can do the following.

1. Add a Derived Column
   [image: DCO]
2. Add one of these conversions
   [image: Convert]

   - Round: `(DT_I4)Amount`
   - Ceiling: `(DT_I4)CEILING(((DT_DECIMAL,2)Amount))`
   - Floor: `(DT_I4)FLOOR(((DT_I4)(DT_DECIMAL,2)Amount))`

**Note:** While I chose to `add as new column` you can Replace that column as well.

Answer (score 1):

Convert() or Try_Convert() to money will handle commas and $ as well.

```
Select try_convert(money,'2,435.00')    -- 2435.00
Select try_convert(money,'$2,435.00')   -- 2435.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `script component`

1. Add a `Script Component`
2. Mark `amount` as input column
3. Add an output column of type integer (ex `outAmount`)
4. Add the following code: *(using vb.net) and asuming that `amount` column is `string`*

   ```
   If Not Row.Amount_IsNull AndAlso
      Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Amount) Then

       Row.outAmount = CInt(Row.amount.Replace(".","").Replace(",",""))

   Else

       Row.outAmount _IsNull = True

   End If
   ```